# Override Load More button for Views

Tags: views, paging

I am currently using Drupal Views and its "Load More" Pager. I wish to change the words on the button to say something else instead.

It looks like the UI does not provide me with an easy way to do that, so I am wondering if there is any easy programming way to achieve that.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to change the text. Follow the steps

In you 'view' you can find **PAGER** settings

[image]

Click on Settings to change the text

[image]

Enter the text whatever you want to see at Output

[image]